# iText7 multiple signature

Tags: itext, digital-signature, signature, itext7

I want to do multiple signatures in a pdf document with iText7 , but the problem is when I have once sign , it works . If I sign twice , the first signature is invalid . It looks like this :

[image]

[image]

[unsigned PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jitakxi83ywzolg/hello.pdf?dl=0)

[signed PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/glbpbgnjfvv8sof/signed2.pdf?dl=0)

and here is my code:

```
@Test
public void testMutiSign() {

    iTextSignerUtil1.SignMultPDF(getBytes(unsignedPath), destPath1);

    iTextSignerUtil2.SignMultPDF(getBytes(destPath1), destPath2);

}


 IExternalSignatureContainer externalP7DetachSignatureContainer = new IExternalSignatureContainer() {
    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {


        //byte[] hashData = HashUtil.hash(data , "SHA256");

        byte signData = null;
        signData = signUtil.signP7DetachData(data);

        return signData;

    }


    @Override
    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
        signDic.put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
        signDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    }
};


public void SignMultPDF(byte[] pdfFile , String destPath , String name , String fname , String value){

    boolean success = false;

    int estimatedSize = 300000;

    while (!success) {
        try {

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfFile));
            PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(destPath), true);

          pdfSigner.signExternalContainer(externalP7DetachSignatureContainer, estimatedSize);

            success = true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            estimatedSize += 1000;
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is all my sample code .

And one more question , did I miss to create signature field ?

Comment: Hmmm, hmmm, the behaviour is consistent with signing without append mode, but the `PdfSigner`appears to be constructed correctly. Maybe you're doing something wrong in your external signing container? Can you share its implementation?

Comment: Could you also share the validation details ? Did you try to validate the signature according to standard ETSI TS 102 853 ? (there are some online tools for that - e.g. Google "dss signature validation")

Comment: Or simply share the sample, twice signed PDF for analysis.

Comment: please also share the sample, twice signed PDF for analysis.

Comment: @mkl I have shared two pdf documents.

Comment: One thing to start with: You use `estimatedSize = 300000`; thus, the place holder for the signature container string will hold at least 300000 bytes which due to hex encoding requires 600000 bytes in file length; such signature sizes are insane. Usually 12000 bytes suffice for the placeholder...

Comment: The observed behavior appears to be due to an error in the original, unsigned file. After lunch I'll look into this some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this issue is a quirk of the [original file](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/signed2-2.pdf): It has an empty indirect dictionary which it uses both as **Info** dictionary and as **Outlines** dictionaries.

Whenever manipulating a PDF iText updates its **Info** dictionary, in particular the **ModDate** is likely to change each time.

Thus, during each signing pass the **Info** dictionary is changed, and as the dictionary object is shared, so is the **Outlines** dictionary. But changing the **Outlines** of an already signed PDF is not allowed. Thus, the **Info** (and **Outlines**) changes during the creation of the second signature are not allowed and invalidate the first signature.

[This file](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/signed2-2-fixed.pdf) is nearly the same as the [original file](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/raw/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/signed2-2.pdf), the only difference is that it uses different empty dictionaries for **Info** and **Outlines** (as there was a currently unused empty indirect dictionary in the file, I merely needed to change the reference of **Info** or **Outlines** to this unused object). When signing this file twice, Adobe does not complain anymore.

---

Is this a bug in iText or in the PDF? I think iText should use a new indirect object number when changing the **Info** dictionary because such duplicate uses of dictionaries is not generally forbidden in PDFs. But a PDF making use of such 
duplicate indirect object uses is really asking for trouble. So I think this question brings both an iText issue and an issue in the PDF into the light.

Comment: Here are some itext7 examples I just found : [SignatureWorkflow](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/signatures/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter02/C2_11_SignatureWorkflow.java) and [LockFields](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/signatures/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter02/C2_12_LockFields.java). It looks like I must create signature field firstly by myself , instead of signing directly , right? So I according this to do some override , create form and fill out , it works .

Comment: But the problem is it will create a table in the pdf , I don't think I need to show this table .

Comment: *"It looks like I must create signature field firstly by myself , instead of signing directly , right?"* - wrong. You only need to do so to enforce a certain work flow, in particular to allow only a predefined set of allowed changes after each signature. In the situation at hand the issue is related to your very pdf add described above.  Simply test with the manipulated version I also shared in my answer.

Comment: My unsigned file is exported from **Typroa** . And how can you generate your file ? I signed it successfully .

Comment: *"how can you generate your file ?"* - As described in my answer, I patched your PDF to use separate empty indirect dictionaries for **Info** and **Outlines**. *"My unsigned file is exported from Typroa"* - Actually your PDF appears to be generated by some producer and then post-processed by some PDF processor (internally it consists of two revisions). If this really is the result of that Typroa software, you might want to inform their support that the PDF they produce is unfriendly to PDF processors processing the PDF further. If the post-processor is different, look for support there.

Comment: Ah, by "Typroa" you appear to mean [Typora](https://typora.io/). And indeed, when Typora exports a PDF, the result file contains two internal revisions; and when Typora exports a PDF with empty outlines, it reuses the empty indirect dictionary.

Comment: @JDNew As a work-around, use Typora PDF exports that have outlines (i.e. entries in the PDF viewer Bookmarks window). Such Typora PDF exports at first glance don't share a dictionary for **Info** and **Outlines**.