# Multiple signature not working

Tags: c#, digital-signature, itext7

I try to port my iText5 code into iText7. I managed to sign an unsigned pdf just fine but I have some troubles for signing an already signed document.

I simplified the code. The following puts some interesting things into my pdf. The code:

```
using (var os = new MemoryStream())
{
    var pdfSigner = new ExtendedPdfSigner(new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\x\Desktop\signed.pdf"))), os, true);
    var external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(external, 8192);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\x\Desktop\tempFile.pdf", os.ToArray());
}
```

[image: tempFile screenshot]

It also shows that "There have been subsequent changes to the document" message in the first signature.

I don't know if it's a bug but I even tried this in 7.1.3 Snapshot.

Signed pdf that I try to sign again is [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dOZT_VGnqVe1II_DIiISGcD81be5V6i6).
Resulting temp pdf is [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lJGSy2juFlNPOjaZV--tvH2QfKDhCfDc).

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217751/itext7-multiple-signature) help?

Comment: @stuartd Nope. Already checked that one.

Comment: What exactly does your `ExtendedPdfSigner` class do differently than the itext `PdfSigner` does?

Comment: @mkl `GetRangeStream` method was `protected` so that I made it available through `ExtendedPdfSigner`. Result would be the same if `PdfSigner` is used though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in iText 7. While retrieving the annotations of the page to add the signature widget to them, all the annotations are touched: an optional reference to their page is added to them and they are marked as *changed*.

Thus, the issue can be reproduced by this code (in Java; similarly in C#):

```java
try (   PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SOURCE), new PdfWriter(DEST), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode())) {
    pdfDocument.getPage(1).getAnnotations();
}
```

*([SignTwice](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/SignTwice.java#L291) test `testStampSigned`)*

Merely executing this getter causes all the annotations on page 1 to be changed and so makes Adobe Reader warn about annotation modifications. If the signature was a certification signature with no changes allowed, this would have rendered the original signature invalid!

*A mere getter **must not** have such side effects.*

Comment: I wanted to port to iText7 from 5 because of .NET Core support. However, I guess it is far too early for that. I wonder when would they release a stable version because there are lots of questions asked in SO which relate to these kind of bugs..

Comment: Yes, there are certain bugs. But please be also aware that new features will only be added to itext 7. Thus, you might consider implementing new functionalities of your product using itext 7 (as they may require new itext features) while still using itext 5 for old functionalities (which is proven to work).

Comment: This bug is fixed in iText7 7.1.6 version or higher